# SQL Server Round and Truncate Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, rounding

So I've come across a strange issue in SQL Server with rounding.

Here's my example:

```
declare @amount float = 178.69999999

select
    @amount as [amount],
    round(@amount, 6) as [round],
    round(round(@amount, 6), 2, 1) as [trim_1],
    floor(round(@amount, 6) * power(10.0, 2)) / power(10.0, 2) as [trim_2]
```

And here's the result I get:

```
+--------------+-------+--------+--------+
|    amount    | round | trim_1 | trim_2 |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------+
| 178.69999999 | 178.7 | 178.69 | 178.7  |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------+
```

The general idea here is that I'm trying to round by 6 decimal places, then trim/floor/truncate by 2 decimal places. This means that I'm expecting a result of `178.7`, but I'm getting a result of `178.69` for `trim_1` (`trim_2` is an alternative approach meant to yield the same result).

From what I can tell, I am using the `round` function appropriately, as the [SQL Server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) states:

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )
> ```
>
> *function*
>
> Is the type of operation to perform. *function* must be **tinyint**, **smallint**, or **int**. When *function* is omitted or has a value of 0 (default), *numeric_expression* is rounded. When a value other than 0 is specified, *numeric_expression* is truncated.

So I would expect `trim_1` to match `trim_2`.

Here's the kicker: if I pass the result of `round` as a constant, and not as a variable, it works as expected:

```
select round(178.7, 2, 1) -- Yields 178.7
```

My guess is that SQL Server is doing something strange with floating points, or I've somehow managed to miss something. For what it's worth, I'm using SQL Server 2014, so perhaps that's my issue.

I'd like to get the result of `trim_1` with as little code as possible, so that my end result looks cleaner.

Comment: Float/real are not exact data types. [Demo using exact DECIMAL data type](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=be2c71cf55370f3fccd405d23e0a1f71)

Comment: `ROUND` with a `real`/`float` simply returns the number to that number of decimal places, as like Lukasz said, it's not an exact data type. You'll need to `CONVERT` to a `decimal`/`numeric` to get the value you're after.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Now that I think about it, all of my decimal columns are either DECIMAL(16, 6) or DECIMAL(11, 9). Does this mean that whatever aggregates I use on columns of these types will use one of those two decimal types? It looks like the DECIMAL data type already rounds values past the specified precision. If I'm understanding everything correctly, does that mean that I could use this: "round(convert(decimal(16, 6), @amount), 2, 1)", or even "round(@amount, 2, 1)"?

Answer (score 2):

Use `decimal` instead of `float`.

Taken from [Float and Real (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly.

Replacing `float` with `decimal` in your code has the desired result:

```
declare @amount decimal(18, 10) = 178.69999999

select
    @amount as [amount],
    round(@amount, 6) as [round],
    round(round(@amount, 6), 2, 1) as [trim_1],
    floor(round(@amount, 6) * power(10.0, 2)) / power(10.0, 2) as [trim_2]
```

Results:

```
╔════════════════╦════════════════╦════════════════╦════════════╗
║     amount     ║     round      ║     trim_1     ║   trim_2   ║
╠════════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╬════════════╣
║ 178.6999999900 ║ 178.7000000000 ║ 178.7000000000 ║ 178.700000 ║
╚════════════════╩════════════════╩════════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: @Boom please mark my answer as correct if statisfies you

Comment: @Boom to [mark an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) just follow these simple steps